# Method for retrying failed batch copies in batch processing

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have an Azure Data Factory pipeline that is copying data from an SQL DB to an Azure Blob. It works by scanning an SQL table and querying the BatchRecord table (a sort of metadata table) and finding all records that have the same projectID and UniqueID (just two ids used to identify a customer and an account). Once all these matching records are found, they are grouped together to form a batch. This batch of records is then used to pull records from a second table and move them to the Azure Blob. There are many records that have the same projectID and UniqueID (representing multiple transactions made by the same client on different dates).

Each copy activity (and some other code) is contained inside a forEach loop. The forEach loop is guided by a lookup activity that uses the projectID and UniqueID to determine how many times it needs to loop. All the copy code is found inside the forEach loop.

Because the number of records is quite large, some of the copy activities in each batch fail because of network issues. My question is this: Is there some way to retry only these failed copy activities after all the records have been attempted once? That is, I want to process all records (regardless of failures) then I want to re-attempt only the failed records. If possible, I would also like to be able to control how many times a retry is attempted (maybe two retries, maybe ten depending on what each client needs). How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Copy Activity in ADF has retry and retry interval settings, by default retry is set to 0, so it does not retry the copy if failed. you could increase the number of retries on the copy activity.

[image]